# Cannot run process on multiple systems using VB script

Tags: vbscript

I have VB script to run process on remote machines.
But it works fine on first machine(first host name in import-text file).

here is the script,

[Let me explain: I have bunch of systems in text file(C:\computers.txt)and trying to run cmd to configure users on HP remote board.

I could see the results(successful), It works fine on first host then i can see error ""The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".]

My question is it should run on all the machines without any error, somebody can tell me where do to insert bypassing line in below scripts.

Also please suggest me on feasible ways to write script.

Could you please help me?

```
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oTS = oFS.OpenTextFile("C:\computers.txt")

Do Until oTS.AtEndOfStream

strCompname = oTS.ReadLine

WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /v:on /k (set MYDIR=C:\Program Files\HP\hponcfg\) & cd /d ""!MYDIR!"" & HPONCFG.exe  /f \\transfer\transfer\c5180150\Add_User.xml /l log.txt > output.txt" 

Loop

Set wshShell = Nothing

wscript.quit


'close the text file

oTS.Close
```

Comment: Where in your code are you using the variable "strCompname"?

Comment: yes, you got my point.. i tried using this in my cmd but got syntax error. so removed off. Am not very that where to call this function.

Comment: yes, if you can tell me where to add word strCompname in my cmd! that would solve my issue.. if not please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use wmic to do it.

```
wmic /node:@computerlist.txt process call create '"c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe" /c "C:\\Program Files\\HP\\hponcfg\\HPONCFG.exe" /f \\\\transfer\\transfer\\c5180150\\Add_User.xml /l log.txt'
```

probably does it (I can't test)

Computerlist.txt can be name or ip.

```
127.0.0.1
computername
```

Command strings because they parsed by a C program need backslashes escaped with backslashes.

If you want the output on your computer use either redirection on  WMIC or use WMIC's Append switch (`/append:"filename.txt"`)

Here are 4 examples showing different abilities of wmic.

```
wmic /node:"@%userprofile%\desktop\ComputerName.txt" /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\NicSpeed.html" /failfast:on nic where (PhysicalAdapter=TRUE and Speed!=100000000) get systemname,speed,caption /format:htable
wmic /node:"@%userprofile%\desktop\ComputerName.txt" /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\NicSpeed.html" /failfast:on FSDIR get /format:hform
wmic /output:clipboard process where "Name='wscript.exe'" get commandline,ParentProcessId /format:List
wmic /node:"@%userprofile%\desktop\ComputerName.txt" /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\Alias.html" /failfast:on alias get /format:hform
```

Comment: Hello, are you talking about just one line to do this function? if so how do this reads system names?     wmic /node:@computerlist.txt process call create '"c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe" /c "C:\\Program Files\\HP\\hponcfg\\HPONCFG.exe" /f \\\\transfer\\transfer\\c5180150\\Add_User.xml /l log.txt'

Comment: Yes one line. If you read my answer I say the computernames, either names or IP addresses (and you can mix like I did in the sample file I posted) are in computerlist.txt (the @ means it's a file of names, without the @ it's the remote system name). Also WMIC uses WMI, vbscript can also use WMI (there are both wmic and wmi tags here).

Comment: So try `wmic /?`, `wmic process /?`, `wmic process call /?`, `wmic process get /?`, `wmic process set /?` (if it has anything you can set), also output can be `/format:CSV`, `/format:table`, `/format:HForm` (a web page list). Also `List` and `HTable` and `XML`.

Comment: Also if you want to type and see commands on other systems see psexec on Microsoft's Website. Any remote command by wmic is invisible on the remote computer (it appears in Task Manager), you can see the commands run when running local.